# prove that $a \equiv b \mod m$ is an equivalence relation on the integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

prove that $a \equiv b \mod m$ is an equivalence relation on the integers

I believe there are 3 properties that it must meet to prove and equivalence relationship. Any reference material would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you know what those three properties are, for a start?

Comment: Check if the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119054/question-about-modular-arithmetic/119061#119061) help you.

Comment: I found this video helpful: https://youtu.be/HatGp_vgqJc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We simply use

- the definition of congruence modulo $n$: for any two integers $a, b$, $a \equiv b \pmod m \iff a - b = km,$ for some  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
- the definitions of the three properties any equivalence relation must, by definition, satisfy: *reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity.*

**Reflexivity**: for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}, a\sim a.$

- Is there a $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that for integer $a$, $a-a=mk$?

**Symmetry**: for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z},$ if $a \sim b $, then $ b\sim a$.

- Is there a $k_2\in\mathbb Z$ such that for integers $a,b$, if $k_1$ is a integer such that $a\equiv b \pmod m$ so that $a-b=mk_1$ for some integer $k_1$, then $b-a=mk_2$, and hence $b \equiv a \pmod m$?

**Transitivity:** for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $a \sim b,$ and $ b\sim c$, then $a\sim c$

- Can it be shown that: $$a\equiv b\pmod{m}\longrightarrow \exists k_1\in\mathbb Z,~~~ a-b=mk_1$$ and $$b\equiv c \pmod m\longrightarrow \exists k_2\in\mathbb Z,~~~ b-c=mk_2,$$ that there must exist some $k_3 \in\mathbb Z$ such that $a-c=mk_3$?

You need only show that indeed answer the above questions, and show why your answer holds, to prove that equivalence modulo $m$ is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 7):

$a\equiv b$ mod $m$ iff  $m\mid (a-b)$ to see that this is an equivelance relation we need to check its reflexive, symmetric and transitive.
1) reflexive, means $a\equiv a$ this is true since  $m\mid (a-a)=0$.
2)symmetric, means if $a\equiv b$ then $b\equiv a$ now if we have $a\equiv b$ then $m\mid (a-b)$ that is $$a-b=mk$$ for some integer k but then $$b-a=m(-k)$$ which implies that $m\mid (b-a)$ i.e. $b\equiv a$.
 3)transitive, means if $a\equiv b$ and $b\equiv c$ then $a\equiv c$ assume that $a\equiv b$ and $b\equiv c$ that is $m\mid(a-b)$ and $m\mid (b-c)$ which implies that $$a-b=mk_1$$ and $$b-c=mk_2$$ now by adding these two equations we get$$a-c=m(k_1+k_2)$$ that is $m\mid(a-c)$ i.e $a\equiv c$ as required.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, as its pretty clear. I somewhat understand the role of k, so if k is an arbitrary integer, the value of k doesn't matter since its a multiple of m? is that correct?

Comment: @shosh Yes, k doesn't matter the key thing is to show that b-c for example is a multiple of m

Answer (score 5):

According to the definition, $a\equiv b~~~(\text{mod}~m)$ iff $\exists k\in\mathbb Z,~~~ a-b=mk$ wherein $a$ and $b$ are integers. Now check that:

- Does exist $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that for integer $a$, $a-a=mk$?
- Does exist $k'\in\mathbb Z$ such that for integers $a,b$, if $a-b=mk$ then $b-a=mk'$? where $k$ is an integer?
- Can we conclude from: $$a\equiv b~~~(\text{mod}~m)\longrightarrow \exists k\in\mathbb Z,~~~ a-b=mk$$ and $$b\equiv c~~~(\text{mod}~m)\longrightarrow \exists k'\in\mathbb Z,~~~ b-c=mk'$$ that there exists $k''\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a-c=mk''$?

Comment: @Clayton: Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is the kind of answers I like. I bet the OP profited from it. +1

Answer (score 1):

For $m=0$, we are talking equality.

For $m \ne 0$, prove first that $a \equiv b \pmod m$ if and only if **$a$ and $b$ divided by $m$ yield the *same* remainder**.

Then it becomes obvious that this is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ a\equiv b\:\ (mod\ m)\iff f(a) = f(b),\ $ for $\rm\ f(n) = n\ mod\ m =\, $ remainder left when dividing $\rm\,n\,$ by $\rm\,m.\:$ But it's [easy to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/297782/23500) that all relations of this type are equivalence relations.

More generally, suppose $\rm\ u\sim v\ \smash[t]{\overset{\ def}{\iff}}\, f(u) \approx f(v)\ $ for a function $\rm\,f\,$ and equivalence relation $\,\approx.\, \ $ Then the equivalence relation properties of $\,\approx\,$ transport (pullback) to $\,\sim\,$ along $\rm\,f\,$ as follows:

- reflexive  $\rm\quad\ f(v) \approx f(v)\:\Rightarrow\:v\sim v$
- symmetric  $\rm\,\ u\sim v\:\Rightarrow\ f(u) \approx f(v)\:\Rightarrow\:f(v)\approx f(u)\:\Rightarrow\:v\sim u$
- transitive $\rm\ \ \ u\sim v,\, v\sim w\:\Rightarrow\: f(u)\approx f(v),\,f(v)\approx f(w)\:\Rightarrow\:f(u)\approx f(w)\:\Rightarrow u\sim w$

Such relations are called *(equivalence) kernels*. One calls $\, \sim\,$ the $\,(\approx)\,$ *kernel* of $\rm\,f.$