# Prove that $a + 2b \equiv 0 \bmod 3$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations, congruence-relations

Would this proof work to show that $R$ ={(x, y) ∈ ℤ<sup>2</sup>: x + 2y ≡<sub>3</sub> 0} is an equivalence relation?

**Reflexive:**

Let x ∈  ℤ.
x + 2x= 3x, and 3x ≡ 0 mod 3 since 3 divides 3x with remainder 0.

**Symmetric:**

Let x, y  ∈ ℤ. Suppose (x, y) ∈ $R$. Then x + 2y ≡ 0 mod 3 -> x ≡ -2y ≡ y ≡ 2x -> y + 2x ≡ 0 mod 3.

**Transitive:**

Edit: Oops definitely did not do the transitive part of the proof properly -- does this work instead?

Let x, y, z ∈ ℤ and suppose (x, y), (y, z) ∈ $R$. Then x + 2y ≡ y+  2z ≡ 0 mod 3. x + 2y = 3m and y + 2z = 3n for some m, n in ℤ. Then x + 2(3n-2z) = 3m, so simplifying that shows x + 6n - 4c = 3n...? Not sure how to get the sign for c to be positive.

Comment: Transitive means that "$a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ implies  $a\sim c$"

Comment: Transitive isn't supposed to be that if a~b and b~c then a~c?

Comment: $\bmod 3\!:\ a+2b\equiv 0 \iff a\equiv -2b\equiv b\,$ so you are done if you already know congruence is an equivalence relation (proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2030303/242))

Comment: In fact, $a+2b \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ is equivalent to $a \equiv b \pmod 3$.

Comment: Or, w/o congruences note $\,a+2b = (a-b)+3b\,$ so $\,3\mid a+2b\iff 3\mid a-b\, $ then use the linked dupe to show the equivalent latter standard form is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

For proving that the relation is transitive,
$$ a+2b = 3m ~~~;a,b,m \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$ b+2c = 3n ~~~;c, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Add both the equations,
$$a+3b+2c=3(m+n) $$
$$ \implies a+2c=3(m+n-b)$$
$$ \implies a+2c \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$

Comment: Thank you, I definitely did not have the transitive part right!